# why is string storage 28 instead of 24

Tags: c++, size

I've been trying to learn more about storage stuff using c++. I knew that they are store in the stack therefore the order was the contrary. However, why when i want to get the reference of the string, it shows me that the storage for that is about 28 instead of 24 since 56-28=28.

here is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    int main(){
    std::string name = "name";
    int age = 18;
    std::string last = "lastname";






    std::cout << &name << "\n"; //140701916868960
    std::cout << &age << "\n"; //140701916868956
    std::cout << &last << "\n"; //140701916868928
    }
```

Comment: The "size" of a string and the entire memory footprint of the `std::string` itself are two entirely different things.

Comment: There is no particular ordering required for location of objects in memory.   Some particular implementations do that for variables of automatic duration (incorrectly described as "stack") but it is not some hard and fast rule.

Comment: There is no requirement that local variables be stored in contiguous locations; they can be stored in registers (which have no address).  You can't derive the size of an object by subtracting pointers; variables can be placed anywhere that the compiler deems convenient .  The compiler is allowed to store (allocate) variables outside of your program's environment (for example, asking the operating system for memory).

Answer (score 7):

- You can't deduce the storage size of C++ objects like `std::string` by doing simple pointer arithmetic.
- Default packing for 64-bit programs is 8 bytes which means that any object stored will be aligned to 8-byte boundary.
- C standard doesn't mention stack at all, and there is no guarantee that variables will be stored in the same order as they are defined.